# Passing a "shell script" as a string to Python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, mininet

I want to execute a string as if it were a shell script in Mininet's `host.popen()` module, which is essentially a wrapper for Python's `subprocess.Popen()`. The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

T="$(date +%s%N)" 
nc 10.0.0.7 1234 < somefile.txt
T="$(($(date +%s%N)-T))" 
echo $T
```

If I save it as a file and pass that into `popen()`, the output is as expected (prints the duration of the nc command):

```
dst_cmd = 'nc -l 1234 > /dev/null'
dst.popen( dst_cmd, shell=True )

p = src.popen( ['sh', './timer.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
```

The thing is that the file getting sent, `somefile.txt`, is different every time I run this script, and it is run several times a second for a few minutes. I'd prefer not to have to write a new .sh script for every file. When I try to pass the script into `popen()` as a string, like this,

```
dst_cmd = 'nc -l 1234 > /dev/null'
dst.popen( dst_cmd, shell=True )

src_cmd = '''\
    #!/bin/bash

    T=\"$(date +%s%N)\" 
    nc 10.0.0.7 1234 < somefile.txt
    T=\"$(($(date +%s%N)-T))\" 
    echo $T'''

p = src.popen( dedent(src_cmd), shell=True, 
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
```

the output is

```
Execution utility for Mininet

Usage: mnexec [-cdnp] [-a pid] [-g group] [-r rtprio] cmd args...
...
```

Why is that? Am I missing something about the formatting that's causing a different (unexpected) output?

Comment: What is calling `mnexec`?  To what is `nc` connecting?

Comment: `nc` is connecting to another host in the network (code updated to show this). I'm not sure what `mnexec` does here; it is passed in as a parameter to the `Popen()` call:     

    `'mncmd' = [ 'mnexec', '-da', str( self.pid ) ]`

I got this from the Mininet source code [here](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/mininet/node.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you want is pass the filename to the script right, that would do the trick?

```
p = src.popen( ['sh', './timer.sh', 'filename.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
```

and in the script do

```
FILENAME="$1"
....
nc 10.0.0.7 1234 < "$FILENAME"
```

That should do the trick. Or possibly I'm completely misunderstanding the problem.

======

EDIT:

As an alternative (and a closer answer to the actual question), you could do:

```
cmd = """echo $(date) HELLO $(date)"""
p = subprocess.Popen(["sh", "-c", cmd])
```

`sh -c` tells shell to execute the next command as literal. Note that you don't need a `shell=True`, since you don't need any parsing of the code

EDIT 2:

That's what you get for answering too fast. You *can* indeed just pass a full shell script to the shell this way. Just don't do any escaping (and possibly get rid of the shebang):

```
cmd = """echo $(date) HELLO $(date);
   sleep 1;
   echo $(date)
"""
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: Wow. That should have been obvious. This works and is much more elegant than passing in a string! But I still don't understand why the other way doesn't work. I pasted the script line-by-line into a shell prompt as per @Serge Ballesta's comment that it must be a shell command, and though it's a bad timing test it still returns a reasonable output (a string of digits). I also tried a single semicolon-separated line to no avail. I am curious about this because if multiple subprocesses try to read this file at the same time, which is possible given my setup, it could cause problems, correct?

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work. Actually, it works in my setup. Also, considering your error, this doesn't actually seem to be the problem.

Reading the same file from multiple processes is indeed never a problem

Answer (score 2):

To pass a bash script as a string, specify `executable` parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

bash_string = r'''#!/bin/bash
T="$(date +%s%N)" 
nc 10.0.0.7 1234 < somefile.txt
T="$(($(date +%s%N)-T))" 
echo $T
'''
output = subprocess.check_output(bash_string, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Though you don't need neither the shell nor any other external process in this case. You could reimplement the shell script in pure Python using `socket` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
import sys
from shutil import copyfileobj
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()
with socket.create_connection(('10.0.0.7', 1234)) as s, \
     open('somefile.txt', 'rb') as input_file:
    s.sendfile(input_file) # send file
    with s.makefile() as f: # read response
        copyfileobj(f, sys.stdout)
print("It took %.2f seconds" % (timer() - start,))
```

Comment: Not exactly. At least the shebang `#!` is ignored. You code will work, because you force exectution through `bash`. But it will be quite different on a Windows system where the shell (`cmd.exe`) does not directly support multi-line commands.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: 1. Obviously, the shebang is ignored. Otherwise, you wouldn't need to pass the `executable` explicitly. 2.  Windows is a completely different question

Answer (score 1):

It's best to avoid using the shell entirely. You can do exactly what you want more simply by:

```
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL
from time import time

start = time()
with open("somefile.txt", "rb") as f:
    p = Popen(["nc", "10.0.0.7", "1234"], stdin=f, stdout=DEVNULL)
end = time()

duration = end - start
```

If you're worried about the time of the spawning of the subprocess being significant then try:

```
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL, PIPE
from time import time
from os import devnull


with open("somefile.txt", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()

p = Popen(["nc", "10.0.0.7", "1234"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=DEVNULL)
start = time()
p.communicate(data)
end = time()

duration = end - start

print(duration)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this include the overhead of spawning the subprocess? I'm timing transfers which are often very short, on the order of milliseconds.

Comment: You can use `Popen.communicate` to delay the sending of the data until the process has been spawned. To be honest I think the waiting on the harddisk reads for `somefile.txt` will be a significantly higher overhead than the spawning of the sub process.

Comment: @Toni: why do you use `nc` command at all? There is `socket` module in stdlib.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, the files are getting sent between shell processes (I think that's the right term). The source and destination are "hosts" in a Mininet network. I could probably run a Python script on each one, but it seems simpler and faster to use `nc`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that mininet popen interface is the same as Subprocess.popen, what you write is wrong. You must pass a command, that can be :

- either an executable file and its parameters
- or a shell command, provided you use `shell=True` - that is something you could type at a shell prompt

**But it cannot be the content of a shell script**

Of course, if the script can be seen as a multi-line command and if your shell supports multi-line commands, the individual commands will be executed. So if you default shell is already bash, it could work, but if the default shell is `/bin/ash` for example, all the commands will be executed by that default shell, because the line `#!/bin/sh` will be seen as a mere comment and ignored.

Example :

foo.py :

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python

a = 5
for i in range(10): print i
```

Execution of file is correct

```
$ sh -c ./foo.py
0
1
2
3
4
```

But execution of the content of the file causes an error because the shebang (`#!`) is seen as a mete comment :

```
$ sh -c '#! /usr/local/bin/python

a = 10
for i in range(10): print i
'
a: not found
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: you can [pass the content of a shell script if you want](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31729137/4279). `subprocess` runs `[executable, '-c', shell_script_as_string]` if you pass `shell=True` -- it works if `executable` such as `/bin/sh`, `/bin/bash` support multiline commands (they do).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: not exactly. It should work here, *provided the default shell is already bash*, but it could not work in my FreeBSD box where my default shell is not `bash`.

Comment: `subprocess` uses `/bin/sh` by default. Are you saying it doesn't support a multiline command on FreeBSD?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : no, FreeBSD is a decent OS :-), I was just saying that commands would not be executed through `bash`. It might matter if there was any bash specific extension in the script - as it starts with `#! /bin/bash`, it could expect be executed with bash

Comment: that is why I pass `/bin/bash` explicitly in my answer that you've seen already

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I understand. AFAIK `sh -c "script content"` is the same as `sh script` or `sh < script`. For decent Unix-like shells, it is the same as `sh -c script`, except for the shebang. For other systems, I only know Dos command.com (sniff ...) and Win32 cmd.exe (sniff again...) for which it would **not** be the same. But I agree that your answer is absolutely correct in this context :-)